# deploy vb.net 2017 application with crystal reports in customer machine

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I finished my project in vb.net 2017 it has some reports (designed by crystal report version 13.0.3500.0)
in my computer it works fine.
but in client machine after I installed the project package in the client machine an error stop me once I tried to display any report
the error says ("crystalreports.engine.reportdocument threw an exception")
any idea
I tried to install cr runtime 32 and 64 in client machine it didn't give any new.

When I try to view any report I get the following message
The type initializer for `CrystalDecision.CrystalReports.Engin.ReportDocument` threw an exception

Comment: You really need to find more information about the exception if you can. Perhaps there is more detail in the Windows event logs which you could add to your question.

Comment: There will be more detail to the exception than that, what does it say?. Too bad nobody told you not to use CR in .net applications, in my experience it is just one problem after another.

Comment: In your installation your need to supply a link to the CR run time library or have it included in the program setup.

More info on crystal reports runtime module :-

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

Comment: I got the following message

Comment: The type initializer for `CrystalDecision.CrystalReports.Engin.ReportDocument` threw an exception